# Philosophical Question Regarding OneToOne Models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a project that is scheduled to be deployed in phases. In each of those phases, a specific table will progressively receive additional fields. As I already know which fields will be added in the future, I could added those just now and let them be empty for now until the next phases are reached, but I was wondering a different strategy. I was thinking in implement the first phase's table and in the subsequent phases create new table in which each of its fields are OneToOne related to the first table.

I'm doing this right? Sounds like a good strategy?

ps.: I'm not a native English speaker. I apologize for any mistake. :)

Comment: I'm with Evan here, either the extra fields now, or add the extra fields later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to look at [Django South](http://south.aeracode.org/). It can help migrate schemas. So if you want to add fields to existing tables, South will help you.

There's plenty of documentation at their website, and also from other sources.